execute some commands after boot
I have a 22.04 server running PM2 on it to provide some node applications.
These applications rely on a shell variable that says if the environment is 'dev' or 'prd'
Every time I reboot the system I have to run
export ENV_TYPE = 'dev'

and then restart all the PM2 processes with
pm2 restart 0 --update-env
pm2 restart 1 --update-env

and so on
How can I build a script that will perform these actions automatically when I reboot the server (not after login, right at the end of boot procedures)? Later on I will look into run the script but now the goal is to create the script

This question is similar to: How can I run a command (a script) after boot?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham I am asking how to build the script first. Then I will look into having it run at startup. The linked question assumes I already have a script

You already listed all the commands you need to build that script. Shell scripts, in simplest form, are just sequences of commands in consecutive lines. If you don't know how to write shell scripts, there's a lot of tutorials available on the net, make yourself familiar with some.


vi ~/$USER/script.sh Replace script,sh to something more descriptive.

press i

paste this:
  #!/bin/bash
  export ENV_TYPE = 'dev'
  pm2 restart 0 --update-env
  pm2 restart 1 --update-env


press and type <ESC>:wq! and then

chmod 750 ~/$USER/script.sh


and you have a script. Move it to a directory in echo $PATH if you need direct access to it.
The next step is to add it to /etc/crontab with @reboot as time or (the better but a bit more difficult method) to create a systemd service so you can add it somewhere in the boot chain and have a start/stop/restart feature,

what if i have to run a command that then prompts you to type something? Like when you do sudo su and it asks you to insert the password. How can I provide the password? sudo is just an example command to replicate the behaviour of mine
